# Double bracket pointer syntax

Tags: c++

I have a C++ program that initializes variables in a struct.

```
typedef struct
{
        LONGLONG    llSeekPos;
        BOOL        bSeekActive;
    
} WavPLAYBACK;
```

I am confused of the double bracket syntax `(WavPLAYBACK*)` what does that do?

```
WavPLAYBACK     *pPlayBack;
pPlayBack = (WavPLAYBACK*)pParam;
```

Comment: It's a cast that converts the type of `pParam` to `WavPLAYBACK*`.

Comment: That's C cast syntax. In C++ you should use the templated syntax like `dynamic_cast<WavPLAYBACK*>(pParam)`

Comment: You also don't need `typedef` in C++.

Comment: [Explicit Type Conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)

Comment: Use `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast`, depending on what the type of `pParam` is. If `pParam` is `void*`, use `static_cast`, otherwise use `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: It tells the compiler to pretend that the type of `pParam` is actually `WavPLAYBACK*`. If that's its actual type, all is good. If not, not.